# Combine multiple GCM messages in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android app which uses Google Cloud Endpoints to synchronize data between devices. Currently in each api call a GCM message is send to all other devices. Often a devices does not only do one api call, but multiple directly after each other. In this situation it gets extremely inefficient to send a message in each call, because then all the other devices make multiple calls to get the new data instead of just one for all.

So my idea is basically after an  api call wait ~10 seconds and then send a GCM message. Whenever a new call comes in and the timer gets resetted.

My problem is I don't really know how to do this in AppEngine. My first idea was a TaskQueue with a task that is named a certain way and has a 10 second delay. In the API call I check if the task is in the queue and if yes I remove it and insert a new one. This wasn't possible because a taskname can't be used again even if the task doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Android app knows the difference between its endpoint calls: knows which is the 'final' call, then it could tell the server whether to notify the other devices.

Even if it doesn't, you could do something on the client similar to what you are talking about doing on the server: keep delaying until it is sure that the last call has been made (e.g. the user is finished updating the data) and then do the 'final' server call which causes the notifications to be sent.   This could be done in a service if you are worried that the app will get killed before that final call gets made.

Or, you could do the same thing in the receiving code of the client: when it receives a GCM notification it could delay before acting upon it.

Either way, I think it really is easier (and cheaper) to handle this on the client and keep the server transactional.

Comment: Thanks I'll let the client tell the server which is the last call.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much easier to have the device explicitly indicate when to send the GCM message?